# Chapter Number in the footer

Tags: fancyhdr

Good morning.
I would like to insert in the footer only the chapter number, before the page number. However, my listing is not working. Where am I going wrong?
Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\chaptermark - \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\subsection{One}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\subsection{Two}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to have `\chaptermark` write to `\leftmark` and/or `\rightmark` and then use that information in the footer. `\chaptermark` is not really a data holder marcro, but rather a datasetter macro. Plus you are using `article` it has no `\chapter`'s so I'd expect it does not have `\chaptermark` either.

Comment: Try `\rfoot{\thesubsection - \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}` to add the subsection number.

Comment: For only the chapter number (not the section number) that would be `\rfoot{\thechapter - \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}`